# Transform CSS to style elements with Razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In light of GMail's [questionable support for CSS](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), I'd like to apply `style` elements to everything in the HTML email I'm assembling.

I'm currently using MVC3's Razor to construct the email, then sending off the generated HTML.  Is there any way for me to write the template with a style sheet, then transform it such that each element gets a `style` attribute with the appropriate styles?

---

For instance, in a normal web page, I would have something like

```
<style>
    a { color:#1c5567; }
</style>
<a href="...">Click here!</a>
```

If a GMail user looks at this, they won't see it in that shade of teal.  However, if I do

```
<a href="..." style:"color:#1c5567">Click here!</a>
```

they will.  But that is a huge maintainability headache.  Thus I want a process that can take HTML with the former style and output it in the latter.

.  For this, I want to take that existing CSS style and transform it such that `style="color:#1c5567;"` gets added to every `<a>` on the page.

Comment: Please elaborate. It isn't clear what you're asking. It looks like you already answered the question, just use css a { color:#1c5567; }

Comment: @Accelerator - If I do that, GMail will strip it out.  I need to take that, then apply it to every `<a>` on the page such that *each and every one* has `<a style="color:#1c5567;" href="...">`

Comment: oh I see what you're trying to do. I know your problem. You need to use `!important` to override the style. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the lamest way to do this but you could use a simple CSS parser like this one [CSS Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20450/Simple-CSS-Parser) and add style attribute as required.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're overriding the style in gmail from an external stylesheet, you need to use !important to override the style.

```
a { 
  color:#1c5567 !important; 
}
```

Comment: GMail will strip any attempt to use a CSS, whether included in `<style>` tags or linked externally, according to what I've found.  That's why I want to inline it.  I could be misled, though?

Comment: No it won't. You can use `!important` and it will work. Trust me, I've done it already. Try it, and when it works feel free to accept my answer.